# Selenium/Java How can I pass desired capabilities to FireFoxDriver, when its already taking in some other parameters?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

this is my current code:

```
FirefoxBinary ffox = new FirefoxBinary(firefoxPath);
ffox.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", ":20");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffox, null);
```

but I also need to add this to DRIVER:

```
DesiredCapabilities dc=new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR,UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
driver =new FirefoxDriver(dc);
```

In the first piece of code, DRIVER is already taking 2 parameters, how can I add this one as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FirefoxBinary ffox = new FirefoxBinary(firefoxPath);
ffox.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", ":20");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffox, null);
```

Your current code is creating an instance of `FirefoxBinary`, setting some properties inside it, and then passing it, along with `null`, into the `FirefoxDriver` constructor.

This matches the `FirefoxBinary`, `FirefoxProfile` constructor.

There is another constructor to allow you to pass in a set of `DesiredCapabilites` too, along with what you've currently got:

```
FirefoxBinary ffox = new FirefoxBinary(firefoxPath);
ffox.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", ":20");
DesiredCapabilities dc =new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR,UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffox, null, dc);
```

(Untested code).